# Render only wireframes in 2D LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm creating a game based in the fixed function pipeline (I know, roll your eyes), and I was wondering if it was possible to disable colors completely and just draw the wireframes. I use textures on my quads, but when I use this code:

```
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_F1)) {
                GL11.glPolygonMode(GL11.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL11.GL_LINE);
            }

            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_F2)) {
                GL11.glPolygonMode(GL11.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL11.GL_FILL);
            }
```

It just only draws lines, and then reverts back to a fill mode. However, you can still see the color bleeding through on the lines when in wireframe mode, and I don't want that. Is there any way to remove that so I have just white lines?

Comment: You would have to disable texturing and colour. The fill mode just changes which fragments are draw it doesn't affect how they are drawn (Hence they still have texture and colour). I don't know how to do this with OpenGL 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_F1)) {
       GL11.glPolygonMode(GL11.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL11.GL_LINE);
       glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_F2)) {
       GL11.glPolygonMode(GL11.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL11.GL_FILL);
       glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
}
```

Also if you are changing colors anywhere with glColor3f/glColor4f you will want to create a Boolean of whether or not you are in wire frame mode.  If you are then at the beginning of each render call, call glColor3f(1, 1, 1).